# Adding Chars to a Stringstream

Tags: c++, arrays, char, stringstream

I am trying to add the numbers only from a char array into a stringstream object. The code is:

```
char[50] buffer = '<15>';
stringstream str;
int page;

str << buffer[1]+buffer[2];
str >> page;
```

Page should now hold the integer value of 15, but instead it holds the value 102.
Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
str << buffer[1]+buffer[2];
```

to

```
str << buffer[1] << buffer[2];
```

The way your code is written, you add characters '1' and '5', which are equal to 49 and 53 respectively, so you get 102 and output it to the stream.

Comment: @user3579220 BTW your code doesn't even compile - please next time show more respect to the people if you want to get an answer for your question.

Comment: @user3579220 Also, if the answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted and/or upvote - this is the way "thank you" is being said here.